# Approximating a discrete distribution with a continuous distribution: why add/subtract 0.5/N?

Tags: self-study, proportion

From onlinestatbook's chapter on "[Proportion](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/estimation/proportion_ci.html)":

> [image]

Why exactly do we subtract and add these 0.5/N values? How does that make our continuous formula more "discrete"?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416150/what-is-continuity-correction-in-statistics

Comment: Seems to be essentially a duplicate of [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213966/why-does-the-continuity-correction-say-the-normal-approximation-to-the-binomia/). See also the extensive explanation [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94334/continuity-correction-error-when-using-normal-distribution-to-estimate-poisson-d/94343#94343) and see some of the discussion here around cases [when it might not work](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58198/using-continuity-correction-for-normal-approximation-or-not/58233#58233)

Comment: If there are aspects of your question you think make it distinct from all of the suggestions above, please refocus the question to clearly highlight those aspects and flag to ask for it to reopen, or compose a new question